# Samsung Galaxy S2 (i9100) stuck @boot & unable to flash

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing, boot, heimdall

Nearly three years ago my Samsung Galaxy S2 (i9100) system completely broke (after about 1 or 1.5 years of what I would call normal Samsung usage :D - a lot of errors and problems, but usually fixable) and wasn't bootable any more and I decided to install CyanogenMod. After some struggling I was able to flash it correctly via heimdall (on Linux) and used it for more than a year afterwards.

At some point it suddenly stuck at the Samsung boot logo (I can't tell any more if there was a specific reason) and I was really stressed by my job so I had little time to repair it. I bought an HTC and still am very happy with that. Sadly, my brother is in big need of a replacement for his damaged phone so I am trying to repair the Samsung.

I found out that it does not only **hang on the boot logo**, but also is **not able to boot into Recovery Mode** by pressing (in that and any other order) `[Vol-Up]+[Home]+[Power]`. I am **able to boot it into Download Mode** by pressing `[Vol-Down]+[Home]+[Power]` though, so I decided to simply try and flash a current CyanogenMod kernel following the [CyanogenMod Guide](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i9100) for my device. Neither the [latest](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/90770/cm-11-20141115-SNAPSHOT-M12-i9100.zip) of the [Snapshot](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=snapshot&device=i9100) nor the [latest](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/134664/cm-12.1-20151114-NIGHTLY-i9100.zip) of the [Nightly](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=i9100) releases and not even an [allegedly](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-install-android-4.0.3-ics-on-galaxy-s-ii-official-rom-how-to-tutorial/) official [4.0.3 ROM](http://loadbalancing.modaco.com/download.php?file=I9100XXLPQ_I9100OXALPQ_XEO.zip) are working, though.

All kernel uploads hang at ~30MB (`cm-12.1-20151114-NIGHTLY-i9100.zip` with a size of `232252K` *@13%*, `cm-11-20141115-SNAPSHOT-M12-i9100.zip` with a size of `210012K` *@14%* and `I9100XXLPQ_I9100OXALPQ_XEO.zip` with a size of `391632K` *@7%*) and the heimdall command respectively breaks after quite exactly 10 minutes of hanging at that percentage. The output is always something like this:

```
root@debian:/home/david/Desktop# heimdall flash --KERNEL cm-11-20141115-SNAPSHOT-M12-i9100.zip --no-reboot
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
Claiming interface again...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading KERNEL
14%
ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
ERROR: KERNEL upload failed!

Ending session...
ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
Releasing device interface...
Re-attaching kernel driver...

root@debian:/home/david/Desktop#
```

The phone does not show a blue transfer bar as indicated by the guide. `lsusb` recognizes the device as the following, which seems to be correct to me:

```
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (Download mode)
```

I have no idea on what to do to fix this or continue debugging. Can anyone help?

---

**[2015-11-19 20:45] Update I:**

I downloaded the [latest ClockWorkMod Recovery](https://s3.amazonaws.com/RecoveryBuilder/clockworkmodrecovery/official/i9100/clockworkmodrecovery.6050.i9100.touch.img) from [here](http://builder.unstableapps.com/#/latest/clockworkmodrecovery/i9100) and tried to flash it, but the result did only slightly change from hanging at ~30MB to hangig at 100% (the `clockworkmodrecovery.6050.i9100.touch.img` I tried to flash having a size of `5024K`). The process is pretty much the same by any other account:

```
root@debian:/home/david/Desktop# heimdall flash --RECOVERY clockworkmodrecovery.6050.i9100.touch.img 
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
Claiming interface again...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading RECOVERY
100%
ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
ERROR: RECOVERY upload failed!

Ending session...
ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
Releasing device interface...
Re-attaching kernel driver...

root@debian:/home/david/Desktop#
```

Again, the command breaks after quite exactly 10 minutes of nothing and throws the `Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!` error.

Sadly there is no CM Recovery for my device on the [CyanogenMod download site](https://download.cyanogenmod.org), so I can't try that out. Also the current [latest of Snapshot](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/135113/cm-12.1-20151116-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1JN-i9100.zip) and [latest of Nightly](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/135236/cm-12.1-20151118-NIGHTLY-i9100.zip) releases are getting the same results as before: Both hang at ~30MB - `cm-12.1-20151116-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1JN-i9100.zip` with a size of `231056K` and `cm-12.1-20151118-NIGHTLY-i9100.zip` with a size of `232248K` both *@13%*.

Comment: I would download a custom recovery for your device(TWRP or CWM) fist, [flash that one with heimdall](http://davideddu.org/blog/posts/how-to-flash-a-recovery-image-using-heimdall/) and then copy the cyanogenmod zip to your device. Then enter recovery mode and flash the CM rom

Comment: See my updated answer. Can't even flash a recovery image - but thanks for the hint, I didn't actually think of that myself.